# Can you forward-declare a namespace alias in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'd like to set up some common aliases in a shared header, so that individual headers don't have to declare it individually. But I don't want to include the headers for the target namespace in this shared header, only declare the alias. Is this possible?

e.g I want `namespace GE = Graphics::Engine;` without including any graphics-engine headers.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't think it will work, though...

Comment: @bash.d Please be very careful recommending "just trying it" in languages with undefined/unspecified/implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: Also... "just try it" in which version of the standard :)

Comment: C'mmon... there are corner cases, but this is a simple syntax question. Either compiler(s) support it or not. Simple test :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can if you declare the namespaces beforehand:

```
namespace Graphics {
    namespace Engine {}
}
namespace GE = Graphics::Engine;
```

Answer (score 8):

Since namespaces are open after being declared, just... declare them up-front:

```
namespace Graphics{ namespace Engine{} }
namespace GE = Graphics::Engine;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against it. It can be done and it is simple enough, but what you are effectively doing is forcing your choice of aliases on all users of your headers.

Say that you build a component using this technique and General Electric buys the software, suddenly they get an arbitrary collision of namespaces. You are creating a conflict for no particular reason. Choose a namespace scheme that is simple to use and as unique as possible and then follow it. Adding shortcuts only complicates code (what's the difference between `GE::type` and `Graphics::Engine::type`?)

Comment: I am declaring the alias _inside_ my own namespace. Does this still raise issues... You could say the same of ANY alias in any header file surely?

Comment: @John: If you like better the aliased name, why did you call the original namespace by other name? While the potential for errors is smaller if it is contained within your own namespace it is not completely removed: let your user type `using namespace John;` and there you can have the conflicts once again. At the end of the day, you are polluting *some* namespace, and the more names there are the harder to reason and the higher the potential for errors.

Comment: So your argument is the language feature is broken?

Comment: @John: No, my argument is that certain language features can be helpful in some contexts and hurtful in others. Using directives, template aliases... these are helpful in that they simplify code, but at the same time work against the division that namespaces create. When that is not an issue, it is helpful, but once you start using this in headers you impose your choices on your users (users of your types).